# Rank of Linear Transformation Preserved

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Show that the linear transformation with rank $m$ on $n$-dimensional subspace $V$ can be expressed as the sum of $m$ linear transformations with rank $1$.

Since any linear transformation can be represented as a matrix product, i.e $\mathbf x \mapsto A \mathbf x$, along with the property of rank of the matrices,

> A rank-$k$ matrix can be written as the sum of $k$ rank-$1$ matrices.

This follows the conclusion.

The proof above is my attempt, and I think I might miss out something, or just have a proof for special case.

Any thought or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your proof that any rank $k$ matrix can be written as a sum of $k$ matrices of rank $1$?

Comment: It is shown in the Wikipedia page for Rank (Linear Algebra). I directly used it.

Comment: It is fine if you can use the result directly.

Comment: I don't find a proof of that statement on the wikipedia article you mentioned. But yes, when you have a proof for the statement about rank $k$ matrices, then the statement of about rank $k$ linear transformations is an immediate consequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give a direct proof in addition to your approach reducing to the case of matrices. Let $f\colon V\to W$ be a linear map such that $\dim(f(V))=m$. Pick a basis $w_1,\dots,w_m$ of $f(V)$ and define projections
\begin{align*}
\pi_j \colon\quad\quad f(V)&\longrightarrow f(V), \\
\sum_i \lambda_i w_i &\longmapsto  \lambda_j w_j
\end{align*}
for $j=1,\dots,m$. Note that $\pi_1+\cdots+\pi_m = \operatorname{id}_{f(V)}$.

Hence, defining $f_i\colon V\to W$ by $f_i(v)=\pi_i(f(v))$ we have
$$
f = f_1+\cdots + f_n.
$$
Each $f_i$ is of rank $1$ since $f_i(V) = \langle w_i\rangle$.